# Redirecting everything in a file created by an executable?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

I have a bunch of executable files and I want to store the output of each one of them in a separate file.

For that purpose i am using following command but `"2>&1"` does not work every time. And sometimes the output files remain empty even though the script does print stuff in shell when run from shell.

What should I use instead of `2>&1`?

```
./$file 2>&1 | tee "$outputFile"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture both stdout and stderr use:

```
./$file > $outputfile 2>&1
```

However, some programs are smart and detect to what type of terminal their output is redirected. They might generate different output if you send it to a file...

Comment: Does the > sign prints stdout and 2>&1 prints stderr to the outputfile? Thanks a lot . :D

Comment: Yes, > redirects stdout, 2> redirects stderr and more specifically 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivy for you help.

Answer (score 3):

Some executables don't just write to stdout and stderr, but instead open /dev/tty and write to that.

So to redirect those it is necessary to do more complicated procedures involving a psuedo-tty.  See the command `script`, for something that can do this.

Comment: so is my command write to capture what is being printed to stdout and stderr atleast?

Comment: Okay Thanks Darron for helping me. I did not know that some executables don't just write to stdout and stderr only. I Wish there was a way to check-mark two answers. But as Ivy's answer helped me solved my current problem therefore I am going to check-mark his answer. Hope you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on Darron's answer, you can use the `script` command to capture all of the output. Here's an example that writes to stdout, stderr, and /dev/tty using a python script, and captures all three outputs:

```
brent@battlecruiser:~$ cat test.py
import sys
sys.stdout.write('o\n')
sys.stderr.write('e\n')
with open('/dev/tty', 'w') as tty:
    tty.write('t\n')
brent@battlecruiser:~$ script testout
Script started, file is testout
brent@battlecruiser:~$ python test.py
o
e
t
brent@battlecruiser:~$ exit
Script done, file is testout
brent@battlecruiser:~$ head -n -3 testout | tail -n +3
o
e
t
```

Contrast this with what happens when you use `2>1&` and `tee`:

```
brent@battlecruiser:~$ python test.py 2>&1 | tee testout
e
t
o
brent@battlecruiser:~$ cat testout
e
o
```

As you can see, the write to `/dev/tty` is not captured. Try executing your command within the `script` command as shown and see if it captures all the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Newey for finding time to help me out. :)